# How to use select with redirect to display content on the page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I would like to know how to get the select values and redirect them to display content on the page

In the example below, the redirect to another page is done, but I wanted the main content to be static and only display the javascript content below

JavaScript

```
    <script>
           function AbrirSecao(secao){
               window.open(""+secao+"", "_parent");
           }
    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <select name="unidade" id="unidade" onChange="AbrirSecao(this.value)">
        <option value="">Selecione sua Cidade</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com.br">Sua Cidade 1</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com.br">Sua Cidade 2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Please see [ask], then provide more information about your page structure. Also, it's not really a redirect if you're simply loading content in the page. Redirect implies a full page change.

Comment: In this example, it redirects to an external page, I just wanted to display a content when selecting the no select option

Comment: it would be a redirect only to the content of the page and keeping the main content static

Comment: As I said, that's not a redirect. It's a retrieval or load.

Comment: yes, but how do I do this recovery?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it and you'll display the value of option in then paragraph tag with content ID:

```js
function AbrirSecao(secao) {
  let display = document.getElementById('content')
  display.textContent = secao
}
```

```html
<p id="content"></p>
<select name="unidade" id="unidade" onChange="AbrirSecao(this.value)">
  <option value="">Selecione sua Cidade</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com.br#one">Sua Cidade 1</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com.br#two">Sua Cidade 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have a box to select options and it redirects to an external page, but I wanted to select the option in the selection box instead and just display content below

Comment: yeah, I understand now, where do you want to display it ? in console or ?

Comment: wanted to display on console

Comment: but I wanted to display not the link itself, but the content of an external page, but keeping the main content static